# vb6: how detect if string is unicode

Tags: unicode, vb6

I'm developing a function that needs to detect if a string is Unicode.

I get this string from an Access DB.

Now i'm analyzing every two bytes: If second is 00 then is Unicode, but not always is so; sometimes I've got a couple of bytes as `&H2` `&HA1`.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you reading NVARCHAR or VARCHAR?   NVARCHAR is unicode, VARCHAR is ASCII

Comment: it isn't nvarchar or varchar.. is a ole object: 
in past someone taken a byte array, convert it into unicode string and copy it in a db field (ole object).
problems comes when we start to change charset table in machine:
getting access db field value, convert it from unicode changes byte array value. 
converting value to right table isn't possible (cause of our system)
but i need to check if a string was converted into unicode

Comment: If you are talking about the `String` data type, since VB4 it has been the UTF-16 (or its precursor UCS-2) encoding of the Unicode character set. If the database column is NVARCHAR that's the same thing but not relevant once you have the text in a `String`—unless whatever constructed the string doing something wrong. Every character is Unicode. So, what is your question?

Comment: BTW—Microsoft has variously used "Unicode" as a name for UTF-16 or UCS-2. They are among several encodings of the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the characters from 0 to 127 are "safe."  ANSI character values from 128 to 255 have different meanings and character mappings in different locales.

For example, in the U.S. English locale:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim S As String

    S = "‰"
    Debug.Print S, Asc(S), AscW(S)
End Sub
```

Produces:

```
‰              137           8240
```

Comment: The only thing "unsafe" here is the Asc function, which is most cases makes no sense to use. String is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. "[‰](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm)" is a UTF-16 literal. AscW gets the first code unit (there happens to be only one in that string). The question asker should examine the storage and retrieval code for Asc and Chr and consider how to repair their damage—if that's even possible with data already stored.

Comment: `Asc` is not unsafe, it just converts to ANSI before reporting a value.  Of course a character that cannot be mapped into the current ANSI codepage gets changed to a "splat" (usually the ? char).

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying data is primarily ASCII/ANSI, then your current check is enough. In 16-bit Unicode, such string data will have a majority of characters whose upper byte is 00. Not 100%, but an obvious majority. This won't occur in straight ANSI string data.

Comment: As I showed in my answer, it _certainly will_ occur for characters within the current ANSI codepage.  His entire point is that a number of characters will make use of the upper byte, thus his check is worthless.

Comment: @Bob77 - Not sure what point you're emphasizing, but I didn't say -- in fact was careful *not* to say -- that all upper bytes will be zero. For ordinary (Western) ANSI data, a majority of Unicode characters will have zero upper bytes. But the real point is that for 8-bit ANSI strings, almost *none* of the bytes will be zero. Therefore a quick count of zero bytes in a given string will give you a reasonable indication of its Unicode status.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223 basically we have seen this question many times.

Comment: @Bob77 - Yes, in the very general case counting 0s is not dependable. But in the instant case it may do fine. It seems like the OP isn't looking for a general-purpose function to test any random string or file, but a one-time (or once-per-DB) way to see what's in a field. It's a situation where I'd try this first, with the understanding that there's a smallish chance of a wrong answer. I haven't seen any other suggestions here, reliable or otherwise, so...

Comment: I suppose if your employer accepts "by guess and by golly" programming that might be ok, but it isn't correct and it can't be, as Raymond Chen pointed out.  Instead the OP should be going back and asking why the database has data in random character encodings.  For all he knows there might be Big5 DBCS or who knows what.